# Group dates by time doing the mean in the rest of the columns

Tags: r, date, datetime, mean

Hi and thanks in advance,

I'd need to group the rows by date of this data set I've imported with: `read.table`. One problem to add is the format of all variables is `factor`:

```
Date;       Time;     Global_active_power; Global_reactive_power; Voltage
16/12/2006; 00:00:00; 4.216;               0.418;                 234.840
16/12/2006; 00:01:00; 5.360;               0.436;                 233.630
16/12/2006; 00:02:00; 5.360;               0.436;                 233.630
.....
17/12/2006; 00:00:00; 1.044;               0.152;                 242.730
```

Instead of group by date I need to calculate the `mean` of every column to summarize all the records during a day in just one row like this:

```
Date;       Time;     Global_active_power; Global_reactive_power; Voltage
16/12/2006;  -           MEAN ALL MEASURES OF THE DAY
```

After doing date I'delete the Time columns since I just need the `mean` of the measures of each day during a period of time.

Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `dplyr` package assuming that your data is in a data frame `df`:

```
library(`dplyr`)
result <- df %>% group_by(Date) %>%                  ## 1.
                 select(-Time) %>%                   ## 2.
                 mutate_each(funs(as.numeric)) %>%   ## 3.
                 summarise_each(funs(mean))          ## 4.
```

In fact, the commands reflect what you want to accomplish.

Notes:

1. First `group_by` the `Date` column so that the subsequent mean is computed with respect to values over all times for the date.
2. Then `select` all other columns *except* for the `Time` column using `select(-Time)`.
3. As you pointed out, the columns of the data to be averaged needs to be numeric instead of factors, so convert each to numeric as necessary. This uses `mutate_each` to apply the `as.numeric` function to each column selected.
4. Finally, `summarise_each` of these selected columns applying the `mean` function to each column.

Using the data you provided:

```
print(result)
### A tibble: 2 x 4
##        Date Global_active_power Global_reactive_power  Voltage
##       <chr>               <dbl>                 <dbl>    <dbl>
##1 16/12/2006            4.978667                 0.430 234.0333
##2 17/12/2006            1.044000                 0.152 242.7300
```

Hope this helps.